# How to create a dynamic source for a multilist in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have the following content tree structure:

- Home

  - Products

    - Product A
    - Product B
  - Organizations

    - Org 1
    - Org 2

      - Org Config X
      - Org Config Y

Each Organization beneath Organizations has a field called "Associated Products" which is a multilist.  This tells the system which Products go with each Organization.  The Org Config data template has a field called "Selected Products".  When I add a new Org Config content item (which always lives directly beneath an Organization) I would like to be able to restrict the items that are displayed in the "Selected Products" field (which is a multilist) to only display Products that are already associated with the parent Organization.  I am thinking there might be a way to do this with Sitecore Query but I can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Sitecore I figured it out.  Basically you have to create a custom control that inherits from MultilistEx.  Then you need to override the DoRender() event.  Before you call base.DoRender() you must change the source (this.Source) to use a Sitecore query.  Previously I was trying to do it in the OnLoad event.  So my code now looks like this:

```
public class CustomMultiList : MultilistEx
{
  private void ExcludeItems()
  {
    ...custom code here that builds a list of Item IDs to exclude from the Multilist source...
    ...list should look like this "@@id != 'some guid' and @@id != 'some guid' and so forth...
    ...you could also build a list of item ids to include. Any Sitecore query will do...
    ...you can use this.ItemID to get a reference to the current item that is being edited in the Content Editor...

    this.Source = "query:" + this.Source + "/*[" + myListOfItemIdsToExclude + "]";
  }

  protected override void DoRender(output)
  {
    this.ExcludeItems();
    base.DoRender(output);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Coded field datasources](http://newguid.net/sitecore/2013/coded-field-datasources-in-sitecore/) would also be a good way to go this too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll probably need to create a custom field for this. Here's some articles related to the subject:

- http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Community/Best-Practice-Blogs/Martin-Knudsen/Posts/2012/09/Creating-a-custom-Sitecore-Field.aspx
- http://gettingtoknowsitecore.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/custom-fields-part-1.html
- http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012_04_01_archive.html

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, it's a good way of achieving it without messing with the other Sitecore types...